# How to access data stored in digital wellbeing [android] using a Flutter/React Native Application?

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, usage-statistics

I am planning to develop a survey tool to monitor app usage statistics for an individual. Accessing data stored in digital wellbeing [android] such as app name, start time, end time, etc. will be helpful for the analysis part. This tool will be an android app developed over flutter/react native.

Is there any way/API to access this data present in digital wellbeing?

If not, is there any suggested workaround for the same?

P.S: This survey app will be given to a limited set of participants upon their consent, so it's legal for our usecase :)

Comment: try use firebase, firebase also has real time database